# bind event after fullCalendar has been created

Tags: fullcalendar

Is there a way to bind event after fullCalendar has been created?

Something like:

```
jQuery( '#calendar' ).bind( 'dayClick', function( date, allDay, jsEvent, view ){} );
```

Answer (score 2):

off course you can.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                    {
                        title: 'title',
                        start: 'start date',
                        end: 'end date',
                        id: 'id',
                        description: 'description',
                        allDay: globalAllDay,
                                                 color: 'blue'
                    },
                    true 
                );
```

Answer (score 1):

this is currently not possible, but i would really like to have it in fullcalendar. will probably be in 1.5 when i rearchitect some things. could you add a feature request to the [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/list)? thanks

Comment: Has there been any progress on this? I'm incorporating FullCalendar into a pretty robust SharePoint application, and should anything fail (such as user authentication) I would still like the calendar to render. That said, my intent is to render out the calendar first and then bind the `Select` event once the calendar is rendered on the page and the user is found. Thanks for any update.